# mule-module-mqtt reconnection strategy failure

Tags: mule, mqtt

I am using the mule-module-mqtt, in particular the mqtt:subscribe component.
Despite having configured the reconnection strategy both in this way:

```
<reconnect count="5" frequency="1000"/>
```

or in this way:

```
<reconnect-forever frequency="5000" />
```

as soon as the mqtt broker is not available, I get an Exception in thread "MQTT Client Comms Receiver":
[MQTT Client Comms Receiver] org.mule.retry.notifiers.ConnectNotifier: Failed to connect/reconnect: Reconnection of listener for: [Topic Filter: .....

Comment: It looks like that mule-module-mqtt is an abandoned project. On which version of Mule are you running this?

Comment: I am using Mule 3.9 CE.
Do you have any suggestion about other working mqtt mule connector ?

Comment: I haven't seen any other connectors for that. You can search in https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange/.
Note that because the mule-module-mqtt is open source you could try to fork an update it.

Comment: Please add the complete error message and clarify the question. If the broker is not available the connector will not be able to connect to it. What is the problem with that?